# What difference occurs in my JSON to have one work, and the other not?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, embed

I have a large amount of JSON embedded into my page via Ruby on Rail's HAML, that on load, gets injected into a variety of javascript views that display analytics.

As so :

```
:javascript
   $(function() {
     var options = '#{raw admin_analytics.to_json.gsub(/'/,'`') }';
   });
```

This was working fine for nearly two years. Until suddenly! This created a JSON parsing error which seemed to fail right around where an apostraphe was being used in one of the values.

We then cycled through a variety of different implementations :

```
     var options = '#{admin_analytics.to_json }';
     var options = '#{html_escape(admin_analytics.to_json) }';
     var options = '#{j(admin_analytics.to_json) }';
     var options = '#{admin_analytics.to_json.html_safe}';
```

And several others flavors, but everything returned the same error, and everything seemed to fail around the same apostraphe. We then tried changing that specific data attribute manually, but it would nonetheless, find some other apostraphe and fail there.

I should add as well, that doing something like `html_escape` worked fine in console, but by the time it was embedded in the HTML, the parts that would break, were not encoded. They remained apostraphes, and therefore, broke the JSON.

Finally, I managed to solve the entire debacle by just writing this :

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON('/settings/load_analytics', function(data) {
      window.MyCustomClass.init_admin_analytics(data);  
    })
  });
```

Which worked!

My question is.. why did that work? Is embedding JSON intrinsically unsafe? Is there a possibility, I missed some more obvious way to embed JSON?

Comment: Neither examples are valid JavaScript (i.e. missing closing `)`, `}`, etc.). When including code as an example, you should *always* make sure you include *valid* examples *without* glaring syntax errors. You also didn't mention what is parsing this JSON (Ruby? JS? Which version of the library?) or what the "error" is that you're getting... I find it disappointing that I need to explain all of this to someone who has asked 726 questions on this site by the way.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Ah good point. I added closures, and you're right, it is with Ruby on Rail's HAML in regards to implementation. The error itself was `invalid token` in Chrome. If I placed it in a JSON Lint, it would also fail there. Thanks for taking the time out of your day to respond. Cheers!

Comment: `Is embedding JSON intrinsically unsafe?`. No, but its a cheap hack we used to do back in 2007. Embedding "data" in a inline script tag always leads to timing issues if you need to use the data in a external script. Put on the big boy pants and use AJAX :). Using ajax would also use the browsers JSON parser so you get an intelligible error message.

Comment: @max Yah, I guess that's what I went with via $.getJSON . Was just curious as to *why* this was broken. But you infer that it's a cheap hack to embed JSON.. Ahh the coding of 2007.